# Filter multiple key values(Array of an obvjects) in one array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, key-value

I have a key and value pair format, i want to filter all the values which are in array into a single array

```
const holiday_expenses = {
  food: [{name: "abc", place: "xyz"}],
  travel: [{name: "abcd", place: "xyz1"}],
  accommodation: [{name: "xysz", place: "xyz2"}]
}
```

Expected Result:

```
result : [{name: "abc", place: "xyz"}, {name: "abcd", place: "xyz1"}, {name: "xysz", place: "xyz2"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get all the [object's values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) them:

```
const result = Object.values(holiday_expenses).flat();
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const holiday_expenses = {
  food: [{name: "abc", place: "xyz"}],
  travel: [{name: "abcd", place: "xyz1"}],
  accommodation: [{name: "xysz", place: "xyz2"}]
};

const result = Object.values(holiday_expenses).flat();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import "_" from lodash;
cosnt obj = {/...whatever you have/}
const res = _.values(obj);
```

Check "lodash", I believe it can make you life better. https://lodash.com/docs/
There are a lots of helper functions to manipulate arrays and objects.